# Selection sort without a loop

Tags: java, arrays, selection-sort

For this program I want to implement an array of sorting and searching algorithms. The array will be filled with random numbers. Then I want to draw each array element as a bar (making something like a bar graph). I have a step and run button in the GUI the step is supposed to use selection sort. The problem I am having is: I only know how to do selection sort with a loop. However, I can not use a loop because I have to show the array being sorted step by step. Can anyone show me how to do selection sort without a loop? I will be adding all of the code I have so far because this is my first time posting anything, and I want to make sure I am specific.

ArrayViewer:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ArrayViewer 
{
    static int[] array;
    static int size;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        //ask for the size of the array until the user enters a size in the right range
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the size of the array (should be between 10 and 80): ");
            size=in.nextInt();
        }
        while (size<10 || size>80);

        array= ArrayUtil.randomIntArray(size,100);//create a random array of given size and entries ranging from 0 to 100
        final ArrayComponent arrayComp= new ArrayComponent(array); //construct an arrayComponent with the random array   
        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //I want the selection sort algorithm to go in here so I can just assign this to my stepButton.


            }
        }

        final JFrame frame=new JFrame("Sorting"); //create and setup the frame
        frame.setSize(1200,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel(); // panel to hold the buttons        
        JPanel panel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // panel to hold the button panel and the array component; uses BorderLayout: read about it in the API

        JButton stepButton=new JButton("Step"); //button to go through the algorithm step by step
        JButton runButton=new JButton("Run"); //button to run the algorithm 
        ActionListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        stepButton.addActionListener(listener);

        buttonPanel.add(stepButton); 
        buttonPanel.add(runButton);
        panel.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START); //add the buttonPanel  at the top of the panel
        panel.add(arrayComp,BorderLayout.CENTER); //add the arraycoponent object in the center of teh panel
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);         
        //print the entries in the array
        //System.out.println(arrayComp);

    }
}
```

ArrayComponent:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;

public class ArrayComponent extends JComponent 
{
    private int[] theArray;
    final int dx=6; //the width of thebars (as well as the with of the spaces between bars)
    private int space=0;
    int index1 =0;
    int index2 =0;
    public ArrayComponent(int[] a)
    {
        theArray=a;    
        space=600-12*theArray.length/2; //space amount on the horizontal axes to center the graph                                      
        //600 is the frame width in the viewer program
        //For each bar 12 units on the horixzontal axis is used including the space following it.
        //something.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }

    public void setIndices(int i, int j)
    {
        index1 = i;
        index2= j;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {        
        Graphics2D pen= (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int k=0;k<theArray.length;k++)
        {
            pen.drawRect(space+2*k*dx,5,dx,theArray[k]); 
            //space: initial space 
            //2*k*dx:  the (horizontal) distance of te kth bar from the start of the graph
            //5: bars are located on y=5
            //dx: the width of the bars
            //theArray[k]: height of the kth bar
        } 
        pen.fillRect(space+2*index1*dx,5,dx,theArray[index1]);
        pen.fillRect(space+2*index2*dx,5,dx,theArray[index2]);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str=("array=[");
        int k=0;
        for (k=0;k<theArray.length-1;k++)
            str=str+theArray[k]+", ";              
        str=str+theArray[k]+"]";
        return str;
    }

}
```

ArrayUtil(creates the random array):

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
   This class contains utility methods for array manipulation.
*/  
public class ArrayUtil
{ 
   private static Random generator = new Random();

   /**
      Creates an array filled with random values.
      @param length the length of the array
      @param n the number of possible random values
      @return an array filled with length numbers between
      0 and n - 1
   */
   public static int[] randomIntArray(int length, int n)
   {  
      int[] a = new int[length];      
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
         a[i] = generator.nextInt(n);

      return a;
   }
}
```

Sorry if the post is lengthy. The program already draws the arrays, it just does not sort them. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what do you mean you "have to show the array being sorted step by step"?

Comment: You can still show the array being sorted step by step even if you use a loop. As a matter of fact you cannot do this (either the sorting or the showing step by step) without using a loop.

Comment: so if the array was {5,4,3,2,1}  and the user he the Step button. It would switch the 5 and the 1 like it is supposed to, but I want to stop there and not sort anymore until the user hits the step button again.

Comment: @Champ change your question to reflect what you just said

Comment: Use the array sorter as a thread (Yes, using normal loops). it would perform only one step, and would block, waiting for the button click from the GUI thread, which would revive the thread to perform its next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `activeIndex` refer to the index of the array element to be sorted next (starting with value 0).

Write a method, say stepSelectionSort, which will execute only the one step of selection sort and return. The sorting begins at array[activeIndex].

{5,4,3,2,1} -> activeIndex=0 -> Step.click -> stepSelectionSort() sorts array element at 0 -> {1,4,3,2,5} -> draw() -> activeIndix=1 -> Step.click -> stepSelectionSort() sorts array element 1.

Comment: this will do it. basically you have a loop but you remember the location (class data - instance member instead of local int) and only do one iteration every time (break and return);

Answer (score 0):

- Temporarily write code to do full sort inside a loop
- Take all code within the loop and put it in a method
- Remove the loop & call the method once each time the user clicks "Step" GUI button